# Entity Framework's navigation properties are null after sort by nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, lambda, expression

I use the following code to convert order by expressions so nullable columns can be ordered by as well.

```
protected virtual Expression<Func<T, object>> GetSorting(string ordering)
{
        Expression<Func<T, object>> expression = default(Expression<Func<T, object>>);
        IEnumerable<Order> sortObjects = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ordering) ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Order>>(ordering);
        if (sortObjects != null)
        {
            foreach (Order sortObject in sortObjects)
            {
                Expression<Func<T, object>> currentExpression = this.GetExpression(sortObject.Property);
                expression = this.CombineExpressions(expression, currentExpression);
            }
        }

        return expression;
}

private Expression<Func<T, object>> GetExpression(string propertyName)
{
        Type type = typeof(T);
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        MemberExpression propertyReference = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
        Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(propertyReference, typeof(object));
        Expression<Func<T, object>> currentExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, new[] { parameter });
        return currentExpression;

}

private Expression<Func<T, object>> CombineExpressions(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, Expression<Func<T, object>> currentExpression)
{
        if (expression == default(Expression<Func<T, object>>))
        {
            expression = currentExpression;
        }
        else
        {
            // Combine the two expressions' body together
            BinaryExpression body = Expression.AndAlso(expression.Body, currentExpression.Body);
            ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[1] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), expression.Parameters.First().Name) };

            // Convert the BinaryExpression to the requested type
            Expression<Func<T, object>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameters);

            expression = lambda;
        }

        return expression;
}
```

This code works perfectly for all non-navigation properties but it seems as if the navigation properties aren't queried anymore. I use a Select expression to load the navigation properties, like so:

```
protected override Expression<Func<Resource, ResourceViewModel>> Selector
{
        get
        {
            return (x) => new ResourceViewModel()
            {
                ResourceId = x.ResourceId,
                DisplayName = x.DisplayName,                  
                ResourceType = x.ResourceType != null ? x.ResourceType.Name : string.Empty,
            }
        }
}
```

If I don't have anything to order by, the navigation properties are loaded. But as soon as there is anything to order by, the navigation property is null. If I would skip the ternary operation and straightly go to the ResourceType.Name property, I'd get an exception telling me the lambda_method has thrown a NullReference exception.

I know ordering navigation properties doesn't work as such but that's not the problem. Ordering by 'regular' properties causes the problem.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Let start from here. Order by expressions cannot be combined like predicates, but need to be chained with `OrderBy/ThenBy`. Which means you need a different approach - `IQueryable<T>` extension method instead of expression returning method. When applying order by expressions, there is no need to convert them to type `object`.

Comment: I agree with your first statement, but your second approach doesn't seem to be right. You need to define a TKey type for the ordering. Because my scenario must be able to accept any type, I just used object. But neither of  those two statements are relevant for my question. I have created a workaround for this problem but I'm still curious if this is possible.

Comment: The problem is though that `Expression<Func<T, int>>` is not the same (cannot be cast to) `Expression<Func<T, object>>`. Also, when you use something like this `Expression<T, object>> e = x => x.IntProperty`, the resulting expression body is not a member access as one can expect from the above, but `Convert`. Why do you think the `OrderBy/ThenBy` declare a second generic argument if it was so easy to omit it.

Comment: That makes sense but somehow the sorting does work that way, especially since I want to have the conversion take place (because of nullable properties). But maybe that could be the reason why the navigation properties aren't included in the process anymore?

Comment: It would be easier if you provide a small but full example. When you build query manually, it's translated to SQL, and in that context there is no need of special `null` handling because databases support `null` naturally (in both `order by`, `select` etc.), and in that context there is no real navigation property "load". If you are getting NRE from the selector, most probably at some earlier point you have switched to LINQ to Objects. Again, it would help if you provide a sample model and manual query showing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue wasn't as complex as I thought. The problem was that I created the wrong expression tree. You can nest the expression so you can navigate to the property of a property.

The solution below should explain this (this isn't how I actually solved the issue but it should make it clear):

```
private Expression<Func<T, object>> GetExpression(string parentClass, string propertyName)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");

    // Get parent class expression
    // Will result in (x) => x.MyNavigationPropertyWhichIsAClass
    MemberExpression propertyReference1 = Expression.Property(parameter, parentclass);

    // Navigate to the property of the navigation property class
    // Will result in (x) => x.MyNavigationPropertyWhichIsAClass.MyPropertyIWantToSort
    MemberExpression propertyReference2 = Expression.Property(propertyRefernce1, propertyName);

    Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(propertyReference2, typeof(object));
    Expression<Func<T, object>> currentExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, new[] { parameter });
    return currentExpression;

}
```